# SQL Inner Joins Giving Incorrect Count Values in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, join, count

I am trying to use join to connect multiple tables in MS Access to get count values. But I don;t know it gives wrong count values. If I try to join them individually, then it gives me correct count values.

I have 3 Tables. Table 2 and Table 3 are independent and are connected to Table 1. Test 2 and test 3 are basically text values and I want to count the rows .

Table1(ID1(Primary Key),Name)
Table2(ID2(Primary Key), ID1(Foreign Key), Test2)
Table3 (ID3(Orimary Key), ID1(Foreign Key), Test3)

The Query that I get from MS Access is given below:

```
SELECT Table1. ID1, Count(Table2.Test2) AS CountOfTest2, Count(Table3.Test3) AS CountOfTest3
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID1 = Table2.ID2) 
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1. ID1 = Table3.ID3
GROUP BY Table1.ID1;
```

But this gives me wrong Count Values.
Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: the counts are being inflated by the added join of a 1-M relationship. So you either need to get the counts via a inline query/view before the final table join, OR, if access supports it, `count(Distinct table2.test2)` thus counting a distinct unique field values before the join thus eliminating the duplication caused by the join.

Comment: Just to clarify what @xQbert stated; it is not an issue with access, it is inherent and intended behavior in multiple joins involving one or more 1-M relationship, in all flavors of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I can assume test2 and test 3 are unique to each record (perhaps it would be better to count the PK?)

```
SELECT Table1.ID1
     , Count(distinct Table2.Test2) AS CountOfTest2
     , Count(distinct Table3.Test3) AS CountOfTest3
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
  ON Table1.ID1 = Table2.ID2
INNER JOIN Table3 
  ON Table1.ID1 = Table3.ID3
GROUP BY Table1.ID1;
```

Or you may have to get the counts before the joins though the use of inline views.  You could use window functions if MSSQL SERVER but Access needs the inline views.

```
SELECT A.ID1
     , B.CountOfTest2
     , C.CountOfTest3
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Table2.ID2, count(table2.test) as CountOfTest2
            FROM Table2
            GROUP BY Table2.id) B
  ON Table1.ID1 = B.ID2
INNER JOIN (SELECT Table3.id, count(table3.test3) as CountOfTest3
            FROM Table3 
            GROUP BY Table3.id) C
  ON B.ID1 = C.ID3
GROUP BY A.ID1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried these but it does not work and gives me syntax errors since I am using MS access.  Just to clarify Table1 has 1:M relationship with Table 2 and also Table 1 has 1:M with Table3. I am correcting my previous query as I joined by using PK.                    SELECT Table1. ID1, Count(Table2.Test2) AS CountOfTest2, Count(Table3.Test3) AS CountOfTest3
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID1 = Table2.ID1) 
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1. ID1 = Table3.ID1
GROUP BY Table1.ID1

Comment: I find it odd that the last one failed.  What error were you getting?  oops missing an inner join text.

Answer (score 0):

When I use it individually, it gives me correct count value:

SELECT Table1. ID1, Count(Table2.Test2) AS CountOfTest2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID1 = Table2.ID1
GROUP BY Table1.ID1;

SELECT Table1. ID1, Count(Table3.Test3) AS CountOfTest3
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID1 = Table3.ID1
GROUP BY Table1.ID1;

But when I try to join Table1, Table2 and Table 3 in MS Acces, it gives me incorrect count values.

SELECT Table1. ID1, Count(Table2.Test2) AS CountOfTest2, Count(Table3.Test3) AS CountOfTest3 FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID1 = Table2.ID1) INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1. ID1 = Table3.ID1 GROUP BY Table1.ID1

As per my understanding it is taking the count value of 1st query in the parenthesis and multiplying it with the count values of the other inner join.

I have tried many things but don't know what to do. Access adds parenthesis for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yup i had the same problem when i was trying to do this. just use the double sql function to counteract the html and you should be good. once the query has been doubled it will react like a C++ quota statement. If this fails you can always just quantify the source fields to adhear to the table restrictions. its actually a piece of cake i hope this helped.